# Sencha Architect stuck on Loading <MyProject>.. forever

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Everything was working fine until yesterday. This morning when I came in to work, open Architect, then  open my project from the recent list, the project never loaded. SA stuck on Loading ...

Clicking on close button after sometime, instantly closes the SA window, no not responding, nothing.

Then I tried creating a new project, so clicked on Create New Project green button, selected a default Template and clicked Create.

Same thing again, Stuck on Creating a new Ext JS 6.2.x Classic project... always.

I have tried Uninstalling and then installing SA again.
Also tried delete all SA folders from the C:\Users\ folder to give it a fresh start.

This time it correctly prompts me for Activation code, which it accepts and then I end up in the same situation.

I dont know whats going on or where to find logs.

Using

> SA4.1.0 Build 91.
>
> Platform 1283
>
> Cmd 62129
>
> Windows 10

I suspect it could be to do with Proxy settings, but I have confirmed this is happening on a guest network as well where there is no proxy at all.

I have also tried launching the SA with these parameter: --disable-gpu
but same.

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Same for me, even tried to clear the cache in AppData, but nothing seems to help. Hopefully the devs at Sencha will do something soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Workaround 1:**
>
> **1#** You will need to delete SA cache which is located here:
>
> Code:
>
> OS X:    /Users//Library/Application Support/SenchaArchitect4.1
>
> Linux:    /home//.config/SenchaArchitect4.1
>
> Windows:    C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\SenchaArchitect4.1
>
> **2#** Than you will need to disconnect your computer from the internet (or block SA from using internet) and open your project. Once
>   your project is loaded you can connect internet back.

Source: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?334641-BUG-Can-t-open-any-Ext-6-project-in-any-SA-after-11-Jan

Comment: Good on ya.. I posted the question probably too soon.. I can see forum post being logged today. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:1 can resolve the problem of SA stuck on loading project forever
This is the problem in SA Version 4.1.0 -> arc-4.1.0-windows-64-no_jre.zip

Install the new version of SA Version 4.1.1 -> arc-4.1.1-windows-64-no_jre.zip

Although, it will take a little loading time to open the existing Sencha Project, in SA Version 4.1.1, can avoid this problem

Comment: thanks aemon for answering. I got notification from sencha support about the new version being available today.